# ArrayList IndexOf loop through

Tags: c#

I found this piece of code here.

```
int indexItem = myInfo.IndexOf("Selected");
```

I want to see if there is more "Selected" and, if so, give me the index of the item in the ArrayList.

I have one at index 0 and 4. I know 0 is for the first one but how to get to the other.

Comment: What type is `myInfo`? A `string` or a `List`?

Answer (score 2):

`IndexOf` has an overload where you can specify a second parameter, which is the index at which you want to start searching.

```
int idx = myInfo.IndexOf("Selected");
int secondIdx = myInfo.IndexOf("Selected", idx + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a convenient extension method. I didn't look but something tells me this has to already exist somewhere. On the other hand, I've never needed it. And it might not be horribly efficient.

Here's the `ArrayList` implementation:

```
public static int[] IndexesOf(this ArrayList findIn, object find)
{
    var indexes = new List<int>();
    int startAt = 0;
    while (startAt > -1 && startAt < findIn.Count)
    {
        startAt = findIn.IndexOf(find, startAt);
        if (startAt > -1)
        {
            indexes.Add(startAt);
            startAt++;
        }
    }
    return indexes.ToArray();
}
```

And then, because it's no longer the turn of the 21st century, a `List<T>` implementation:

```
public static int[] IndexesOf<T>(this List<T> findIn, T find)
{
    var indexes = new List<int>();
    int startAt = 0;
    while (startAt > -1 && startAt < findIn.Count)
    {
        startAt = findIn.IndexOf(find, startAt);
        if (startAt > -1)
        {
            indexes.Add(startAt);
            startAt++;
        }
    }
    return indexes.ToArray();
}
```